# Download and display image dynamically

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, hadoop

I have the below requirement. I click on the display link in [the shown page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfGEf.png). I call the javascript function `displayImage` with input parameters are `filename` and `isDisplay`. In this function, I generate an `'img'` tag whose `src="download?filename=DCS.jpg&isDisplay=true"`.

I am expecting this to call the servlet which connects to *hadoop*, gets the `bufferedImage` of the requested image and writes to response `outputstream`.

But this is not displaying the image and the servlet is not even called when i dynamically generate the img tag.

What should i do to display dynamically?

JSP CODE:

```
   <%List<String> filenames = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("filenames"); 
    if(filenames.size()>0){
        for (String filenme : filenames){                   
    %>
    <div id="filename">
        <a href="javascript:submit('<%=filenme%>', 'false')" onclick="javascript:submit('<%=filenme%>', 'false')"><%=filenme%></a>  
    </div>
    <div id="displink">
            <a href="javascript:displayImage('<%=filenme%>', 'true')" onclick="javascript:displayImage('<%=filenme%>', 'true')">Display</a>
    </div>          
    <div id="line"></div>
    <%  }
    }%>
    </div>
    <% %>
    <div id="displayImage">

    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function displayImage(imageName, isDisplay){
var display = document.getElementById('displayImage');
 var parameters = "filename="+imageName+"&isDisplay="+isDisplay;
 display.innerHTML="<img src=\"download?"+parameters+"\"";
 display.style.display="block";
}
```

SERVLET CODE:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(fs.open(item.getPath()));
if (isDisplay) {
    resp.setContentType("image/"+extn);
    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bi, extn, out);
}
```

Comment: You aren't closing your img tag

Comment: Yes, I didnt... What a stupid mistake to do... It worked.... Thanks Patrick.

Comment: `BufferedImage` thing is completely unnecessary. You don't seem to want to manupulate the image (resize, crop, colorize, skew, etc). It's therefore only dead weight. Get rid of it and just stream the bytes the usual IO way like so `Files.copy(path, out)`.